# In Nodejs, if a Readable stream's "close" event fires before its "end" event, does it indicate a problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The question title is the TL;DR.  But here's some background context that may help you understand why I'm asking.

I'm debugging some code that uses tar-fs, like so:

```js
const tarFs = require('tar-fs');
const tarStream = tarFs.pack(process.cwd(), ['hundreds','of','files'];
```

That `tarStream` gets passed around a bit, and eventually it is passed into a function (that I don't own -- it's part of the azure-sdk-for-js package) that takes a `NodeJS.ReadableStream` (called simply `readable`).

In that function, it listens for "data", "error", "end", and "close".

```js
this.readable.on('data', (data) => ... );
this.readable.on('error', (err) => ... );
// and so on
```

The problem is: sometimes the script running all this code hangs indefinitely. Unfortunately, it cannot be repro'd on demand. However, if I run it enough (half a dozen times or so) and I eventually always experience the hang.

What I have observed is when it does NOT hang, the "data" event will fire repeatedly (as expected), followed by an "end" event and everything is good.

When the hang DOES occur, the "data" event fires repeatedly and then the "close" event fires, and "end" never happens. This makes sense, because as I understand it, "close" means essentially that the underlying resources have been closed, and when this happens, no further events will be emitted. I believe the hang is happening because there was more data, but we'll never get it, b/c we're waiting for an "end" event that will now, never happen.(Note: when it hangs, the "error" event does NOT fire, and the "close" event does not pass in any error object).

So two questions:

1. Is there a finite list of things that could cause a Readable to fire "close"?  Specifically a PackStream (which I believe is the type that tar-fs gives back)? I'm trying to root cause why it might be emitting "close" but I have very little insight at this point.
2. More fundamentally, it seems to me like "end" should always fire before close. A "close" event firing before "end" feels like something got interrupted; feels very "exception-like" to me.  But is this true?  Or is it possible that "close" could fire before "end", and it doesn't necessarily mean anything went wrong?

The NodeJS doc explain what both "close" and "end" are, but it makes no mention as to whether or not "close" happening before "end" is usually indicative of some sort of problem.

Comment: `tar-fs` depends on `tar-stream`, which in turn uses `streamx` under the hood. It appears that readable streams from `streamx` should always emit a `close` event as the last event (see https://github.com/mafintosh/streamx#rsonclose). If the Azure lib requires an `end` event, I guess you could listen to the readable stream yourself and emit an `end` event whenever a `close` event is emitted..?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your suggestion may work, but I'm just as interested in understanding the root cause of the hang as I am in finding a solution to it. That's why I'm harping on this assumption I have that `close` shouldn't fire before `end` or it means something is wrong (but I have no documentation that verifies this). Because if I'm right, it means there is a problem elsewhere I need to track down. But if I'm wrong, it might be that I need to do like you said: listen for `close` and emit an `end` when it happens. But if `close` should never come before `end`, that feels like a hack.

Comment: Maybe the library calls `.destroy()` instead of `.end()` on the stream it produces?